# How to remove bookmarks?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, bookmarks

I need to upload a paper (pdf) but the edas system tells me that the bookmarks are not allowed, although there are no bookmarks in my paper because i am using the command :

```
 \usepackage[ bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
```

please any suggestions ?!

Comment: Maybe `\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}`? This disables all links and bookmarks.

Comment: Are you perhaps also including the [`bookmark` package](//ctan.org/pkg/bookmark)?

Comment: how i can check if bookmark pachage  is included ? @Werner

Comment: with \usepackage[draft]{hyperref} , edas reports the same problems!! @Marijn

Comment: Put `\listfiles` before `\documentclass`. It will list all the files loaded (at the end of the .log file)

Comment: I am using Overleaf  @SimonDispa

Comment: In Overleaf you can also see the log file, if you click on the "Logs and output files" button (directly next to the "Recompile" button) then you see warnings and errors (if any) and below that there is a button "View Raw Logs". If you press that button and scroll down then you see the original log file with the output from `\listfiles`.

Comment: @Marijn : yes , that what i have :                                                                           
 Output written on output.pdf (15 pages, 2819970 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 146 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 80 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 109 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

Comment: I also try to deactivate the bookmarkpackage but still its not working. \documentclass[journal,twoside,hidelinks,a4paper,bookmarkpackage=false]{IEEEtran}